# Natural Gradient Learning vs Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent

What is the main difference between Natural Gradient learning solutions and stochastic/batch gradient descents?

I read how Natural Gradient is meant to use the Riemannian structure instead of the Euclidian, but I am struggling to understand what that means.

Comment: Did you check the literature? There is enough available i think. I did not hear of this until now, but it just looks like a 2nd-order-method opposed to SGD which is a first-order method. In practice this usually means: less iterations for convergence but much more computation per iteration. (It's not really used in current DeepLearning as it's usually worse in regards to performance)

Comment: @sascha I found a few articles and understood the part about worse performance when reading. But as a non-scholar I got lost trying to understand what the papers were saying overall